# Mistake in proof of: $f$ continuous in $[0,1]$ and such that $f(0)=0, \int_0^1 f(x)dx=1$ implies maximum of $f$ greater than $1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification

I'm probably doing something wrong because I am not using one of the hypotheses, but I can't see the mistake.

Problem: let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that
$$f(0)=0, \\ \int_0^1 f(x)dx=1$$
Show that the maximum of $f$ is greater that $1$.

I've tried this argument: since $f$ is continuous and $[0,1]$ is compact, by the extreme value theorem there exists $m\in\mathbb{R}$ and $M\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $m\le f(x)\le M$ for any $x  \in [0,1]$.

Integrating in the interval $[0,1]$, it is then
$$\int_0^1 m dx \le \int_0^1 f(x) dx \le \int_0^1 Mdx\implies M \ge \int_0^1f(x)dx$$
But by hypothesis, it is $\int_0^1f(x)dx=1$; hence $M \ge 1$, that is the maximum of $f$ in $[0,1]$ is greater than $1$. However, I'm not using the fact that $f(0)=0$. Where is my mistake?

Comment: You recieved 3 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, consider *accepting* the best answer and upvoting all useful answers you got. That's how the site works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no mistake, but the proof is not finished.

You only proved that $M\geq 1$. You have to prove that $M>1$.

In fact, without the assumption that $f(0)=0$, you could very well have $M=1$, since the constant function $f$ for which $\forall x\in[0,1]: f(x)=1$ is a possibility.

---

However, if $f(0)=0$, then $M=1$ is impossible, but you still have to show that.

To do that, I would advise you to split the interval into two parts, $[0,1]=[0,\delta]\cup[\delta,1]$.

Then, if you pick a small enough $\delta$, you can be sure that $f$ is "small" on the entire interval, meaning the integral $\int_0^\delta f(x)dx$ will also be small. In turn, this forces the integral $\int_\delta^1 f(x)dx$ to be such that $f$ must be larger than $1$ at some point.

Comment: Hi, sorry if I write here this late but I didn't end this problem until now. I tried as you said, that is I used the continuity of $f$ in $0$ and $f(0)=0$ to obtain that $f(x)<\epsilon$ in $[0,\delta]$ and so $1=\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\int_0^\delta f(x)dx+\int_\delta^1 f(x)dx<\epsilon \delta+M(1-\delta)=\epsilon \delta +M-M\delta$. Since this holds for any $\epsilon>0$, it is $1 \le M-M\delta \implies M \ge 1+M\delta$. Since I already shown that $M \ge 1$ and since $\delta>0$, it is $M\delta >0$ and so  $M \ge 1+M\delta >1 \implies M>1$. Is this correct? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Addendum to the existing answers: If you know the following result

> **Lemma**: Let $g$ be a continuous non-negative function on $[a,b]$. Then
> $$
> \int_a^bg(x)\,dx=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad g=0\text{ on }[a,b].
> $$

then you may also start as follows:

Assume that $f\le 1$ on $[0,1]$. Then $g=1-f\ge 0$ and
$$
\int_0^1 g(x)\,dx=0.
$$
By the lemma above, it implies $g=0$, i.e. $f=1$, on $[0,1]$ (contradiction with $f(0)=0$).

---

*Proof of the lemma*: set
$$
G(x)=\int_a^x g(t)\,dt.
$$
Then
$$
0=G(a)\le G(x)\le G(b)=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad G=0\text{ on }[a,b].
$$
Hence, $G'=g=0$.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any mistake. If you want $M>1$, instead of $M\ge 1$, you have to use the hypothesis $f(0)=0$ that, in addition with continuity, implies in a neighbourhood of $0$ the function is strictly lower than $1$.